# jquery masked input Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following function in my JS file:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#ccNum").mask("9999 9999 9999 999?9999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });
});
```

Here is the input from the cshtml page:

```
 @Html.Label("Card Number", new { @for = "ccNum" })
```

and here is the bundle that I have linked on the page:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerymask").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.intellisense.js",
                    "~/Scripts?jquery-1.9.0.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
            ));
```

When I am loading this page I get the error Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure jQuery.js loads before any plugins or other code that depends on it

Comment: is there an `id` on your label at all?  pretty sure there's no `id` and only a `for` attribute the way you've written it.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong tag.  Here is the razor page tag:

 @Html.TextBox("CardNumber", null, new { id = "ccNum" })

Comment: The error I am getting is on the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @charlietfl is correct - you are loading `jquery.maskedinput.min.js` before jquery.

Change your bundle definition so it loads afterwards:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerymask").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js",        // first script - also ? changed to /
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.intellisense.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"   // last script
            ));
```

Also there was a question-mark in one of those script definitions.